# Android Studio : Can't use install task of maven plugin

Tags: android, maven, gradle, installation, local

In an android studio project, i can't use the install task of the maven plugin to install apk in my local repository.

I have added :

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

When i display the tasks with ./gradlew tasks, i can see :

```
Upload tasks
------------
uploadArchives - Uploads all artifacts belonging to configuration     ':plugin:archives'
```

But the following is missing :

```
Other tasks
-----------
install - Installs the 'archives' artifacts into the local Maven repository.
```